# Creating multiple tables of contents (multiple header 1 styles) removes the capability of having figures and tables numbered by chapter

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm working on a complex Word document for a client. This word document is for me to set the styles and then hand over to the client to work on the document further, inputting all the text.

They have asked for a table of contents for each chapter which I have done, by creating new header 1 styles - eg chapter 1 header 1; chapter 2 header 1; chapter 3 header 1 etc.

However - the figures and tables within the document need to be numbered by chapter also. Eg. In Chapter 3, figures are Figure 3-1; Figure 3-2. In Chapter 4, figures are Figure 4-1 etc.

My issue us once you have changed the heading style this way to create the table of contents for each chapter, the auto formatting for figures and tables is lost - all start at Figure 1-1; Figure 1-2 - no matter what chapter they are in.

I've traced the issue back to the name changing of Header 1. If I revert to Heading 1 and remove "Chapter 3 Heading 1" style it goes back to the correct numbering of figures and tables.

Is there a way around this or is it that if you have multiple header 1 styles to allow multiple tables of contents, one cannot then have figures and tables references by chapter?

Comment: Why do you actually *need* multiple header 1 *styles*?

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate method for creating multiple tables of content in
one Word document.

The following text comes from the article
[Using Multiple Tables of Contents](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T010080_Using_Multiple_Tables_of_Contents.html).

> 1. Select all of the text you want included in the TOC and assign a bookmark (such as PARTx) to the text. (How you create bookmarks is,
>    again, beyond the scope of this tip by has been covered elsewhere in
>    WordTips.)
> 2. Create a TOC based on the headings in your document. When you are done, this TOC will apply to the entire document.
> 3. Position the insertion point just before the TOC you just created.
> 4. Press **Alt+F9**. All of the fields in your document are changed so that they show the field codes instead of the results of the field
>    codes.   This means that you'll see the field code for the TOC you
>    just entered; it will look something like this:
>
>    ```
>    { TOC \o "1-2" \h \z \u }
>    ```
>
>    Modify the field code so that it looks similar to this:
>
>    ```
>    { TOC \o "1-2" \h \z \u \b PARTx }
>    ```
> 5. Press **Alt+F9**. This toggles Word so that it shows the results of the field codes. Your TOC should again be visible, but it still needs to
>    be updated.
> 6. Position the insertion point within the TOC and press F9. If prompted, indicate you want to update the entire table.

This method is not new and has worked in many past versions of Word.